How do you quickly pan (swipe) through a big schematics page in KiCad?
I am pulling my hair out on KiCad with big schematics pages, I need to be able to quickly pan (swipe) through a page that is zoomed big enough that I can work in it, I am looking for a "hand" tool but there is nothing, everything is selecting stuff and I can't just move the page under my viewport! What am I missing? I can't be the first person in the world trying to work on bigger schematics in KiCad!

I'm not a user of KiCad to check it, but does Navigating the editing canvas help?

Does the manual say it has such a feature and how to use it? Have you asked on KiCad support forums?

Alt+Arrow works  or maybe Alt + Swipe ( I don't have swipe on my TV ;)

Mouse/keyboard shortcuts for horizontal and vertical scroll.

Use your middle or right mouse button to pan (by default).

KiCad also supports infinite panning, so if you are zoomed in, just keep dragging to the right and your mouse will move you to the left edge once you run out of screen space.

Actually only the right one works for me, the middle is somehow captured by my Lenovo mouse thing to do other stuff. But your answer did it, I will insert the word "or right" and then accept it.
